# Help converting subquery to query with joins

Tags: sql, mysql, left-join

I'm stuck on a query with a join. The client's site is running mysql4, so a subquery isn't an option. My attempts to rewrite using a join aren't going too well.

I need to select all of the contractors listed in the contractors table who are not in the contractors2label table with a given label ID & county ID. Yet, they might be listed in 
contractors2label with other label and county IDs.

Table: contractors

> cID (primary, autonumber)
>   company (varchar)
>   ...etc...

Table: contractors2label

> cID
>   labelID
>   countyID
>   psID

This query with a subquery works:

```
SELECT company, contractors.cID
   FROM contractors
   WHERE contractors.complete = 1
   AND contractors.archived = 0
   AND contractors.cID NOT IN (
     SELECT contractors2label.cID FROM contractors2label
        WHERE labelID <> 1 AND countyID <> 1
   )
```

I thought this query with a join would be the equivalent, but it returns no results. A manual scan of the data shows I should get 34 rows, which is what the subquery above returns.

```
SELECT company, contractors.cID
   FROM contractors 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN contractors2label ON contractors.cID = contractors2label.cID
   WHERE contractors.complete = 1
   AND contractors.archived = 0
   AND contractors2label.labelID <> 1
   AND contractors2label.countyID <> 1
   AND contractors2label.cID IS NULL
```

Comment: +1 for being new here, and managing to provide a properly formatted question with a good description of your problem including sample code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When doing a `LEFT JOIN`, you need to put all conditions of the `JOIN` into the `ON` clause.

In your example you get `NULL` for left joined columns that do not exist, but you then compare them to values again (`<> 1`) which does not work.

```
SELECT c.company, c.cID
   FROM contractors c
   LEFT JOIN contractors2label c2
          ON ( c2.cID = c.cID AND c2.labelID <> 1 AND c2.countyID <> 1 )
   WHERE c.complete = 1
   AND c.archived = 0
   AND c2.cID IS NULL
```

BTW: Using aliases (like `c` in my example) makes reading and writing your queries easier.

Comment: OK, I shouldn't have jumped so fast. When I plug it into my app it's actually not working.

Comment: @Tim: Can you describe the problems you are facing?

Comment: My fault...my logic is backward. Your query will give me what I need if I change to ON ( c2.cID = c.cID AND c2.labelID = 1 AND c2.countyID = 1 )  BTW, I think @Nick's answer below will also work, with the <> to = change.

Comment: @Tim: I agree, Nicks answer should work too. I think you should up-vote it - and you can up-vote mine too, if you like ;-)

Comment: I just created an account here so I could up-vote the answers. Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 2):

When you restrict on a where clause using the columns in a table that's `LEFT` joined, you are effectively removing the `LEFT OUTER` part of the join, because you're filtering on columns that have to be there.  Try this instead:

```
SELECT company, contractors.cID
   FROM contractors 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN contractors2label 
       ON (contractors.cID = contractors2label.cID
           AND contractors2label.labelID <> 1
           AND contractors2label.countyID <> 1)
   WHERE contractors.complete = 1
   AND contractors.archived = 0
   AND contractors2label.cID IS NULL
```

This does the restriction as part of the join, so nulls can still be used in the larger query.